# Finding acute triangle probability

Tags: probability-theory

A stick is broken in three parts of any length ,  if we join the pieces then what's the probability of getting a acute angled triangle?

Comment: This problem has been answered several times on Math.SE.  Since you ask for a probability, it is necessary to work with a probability distribution of the lengths into which the stick is broken.  There is more than one reasonable interpretation of how to proceed in breaking the stick.

Comment: To characterize acuteness, you can use the Pythagorean Theorem. That is, If $a \le b \le c$ are the stick lengths in increasing order, then you need both $a+b > c$ for the sticks to form a triangle, and $a^2+b^2 > c^2$ for the triangle to be acute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating probability for forming a triangle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383434/calculating-probability-for-forming-a-triangle)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. It sure is related to the linked question.

Comment: I think this question is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962301/acute-triangle-from-a-stick, but that question was not answered.

Comment: The interested Reader may want to look at [the write-up here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/buffon/Triangles.html) which completes the discussion of chance of forming a triangle with details regarding the acute and obtuse outcomes.

Comment: See [this post] for a relevant simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG the stick has length 1, here the experience can be modeled  e.g. by choosing two cutting points $x_1 \le x_2$ uniformly at random in $[0, 1]$. Then we have three sticks with length $l_1=x_1$, $l_2=x_2-x_1$ and $l_3=1-x_2$.

Then you can notice geometrically that the triangle formed with them is acute iff. $\sqrt{l_2^2-l_1^2} \le l_3 \le \sqrt{l_1^2+l_2^2}$ (the two extreme cases are obtained for right triangles).

Comment: The condition in the last paragraph assumes that $l_2>l_1$. But I think putting an absolute value around the difference would fix that.